# where to put addCommand when implement ajax callback commands

Tags: 8, ajax

i' m trying to load a dynamic value on every node of my site and i want to achieve this via ajax callback commands and writing custom module
so i have a class  in src/ajax folder of module like:

```
class TestCommand implements CommandInterface
{
..
  public function render() {
    return array(
      'command' => 'test',
      'text' => $this->message,
    );
  }
}
```

also a js file:

```
(function($, Drupal) {
  alert('loaded');
  /**
   * Add new command for reading a message.
   */
  Drupal.AjaxCommands.prototype.test = function(ajax, response, status){
    alert('called');
    console.log(response);
  }
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

but i don't know where i am supposed to put this below lines to call command on every node/view.
if i put this in `mytheme_preprocess_node` -checking with var_dump()- i can see
correct response but it doesn't call `Drupal.AjaxCommands.prototype.test`

```
  //where to put this lines to call test command on every node view.
  $response = new AjaxResponse();
  $response->addCommand( new TestCommand('someparam'));
  return $response;
```

js file is loaded because i get 'loaded alert'.

lots of examples on sites, call this via ajax callback in form.
[one](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/226751/manually-invoking-ajax-commands-when-an-ajax-callback-is-not-an-ajax-form-callb) have different approach but i don't know how to apply these solutions in my situation.

Comment: You put it in a controller like shown in the linked question, not the answers. Then this topic might be helpful how to trigger the ajax controller: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/230312/how-to-trigger-existing-non-form-ajax-from-javascript-event

Comment: @4k4 thank you. after reading your comment i end up with adding Drupal.ajax({url: endpoint}).execute(); at the end of js file and putting addcommand in controller. now it works. but i can not find how to pass node id via ajax to controller. also i am going to accept your answer if you post it because it solved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put it in a controller like shown in the linked question, not the answers. Then this topic might be helpful how to trigger the ajax controller: [How to Trigger Existing, Non-Form Ajax from JavaScript Event](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/230312/how-to-trigger-existing-non-form-ajax-from-javascript-event)

For passing the node ID to the controller use a route parameter:

```
myModule.myRoute:
  path: '/myajax/node/{node_id}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\myModule\MyController::getNode'
    _title: 'Node'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

Now you can add the node ID to the endpoint url

```
var url = '/myajax/node/' + node_id;
Drupal.ajax({url: url}).execute();
```

and received it by the controller:

```
public function getNode($node_id) {
```